# Error when creating Collection with SolrCloud and Zookeeper

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I’m trying to test  SolrCloud with Vagrant. I’ve got Zookeeper running on one box, and Solr running on another. The boxes are on a private network (I can ssh into either from each).

When I try to create a collection via the Solr CLI, it times out, I think when it’s trying to communicate with Zookeeper.

Zookeeper is running as expected. I’m starting it in foreground mode with the command below:

```
sudo bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground
```

My zoo.cfg file:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/1
clientPort=2181
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
```

I’m then starting Solr in cloud mode:

```
 bin/solr start -c -z 172.28.128.3:2181
```

At this point, all seems well. Nothing bad shows up in the Solr logs, and no alarming messages coming through in the console for Zookeeper.

I then try and create a collection with the command below:

```
  bin/solr create -c mycollection -d data_driven_schema_configs
```

It’s then that I start seeing lots of errors in the Solr logs, and lots of repetitive messages appearing in Zookeeper:

These two Solr errors over and over:

```
 java.io.IOException: Xid out of order. Got Xid 1299 with err 0
 expected Xid 1298 for a packet with details: clientPath:null
 serverPath:null finished:false header:: 1298,14  replyHeader:: 0,0,-4 
 request:: org.apache.zookeeper.MultiTransactionRecord@95acc4f3
 response:: org.apache.zookeeper.MultiResponse@0

 There was a problem trying to register as the leader:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 
 Could not register as the leader because creating the ephemeral registration 
 node in ZooKeeper failed
```

And this from Zookeeper:

```
[NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn$Factory@251] - Accepted socket connection from /172.28.128.4:54548
2016-08-21 21:33:39,137 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@770] - Client attempting to renew session 0x156aefeba2d0004 at /172.28.128.4:54548
2016-08-21 21:33:39,145 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1580] - Established session 0x156aefeba2d0004 with negotiated timeout 15000 for client /172.28.128.4:54548
2016-08-21 21:33:39,147 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@593] - Dropping packet at server of type 14
2016-08-21 21:33:39,154 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@634] - EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x156aefeba2d0004, likely client has closed socket
2016-08-21 21:33:39,155 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1435] - Closed socket connection for client /172.28.128.4:54548 which had sessionid 0x156aefeba2d0004
2016-08-21 21:33:40,698 - INFO
```

I can’t understand what’s going on here. I feel like the key is in that Solr error:

```
Could not register as the leader because creating the ephemeral registration node in ZooKeeper failed
```

But when searching around on that error I can’t find anything useful. Can anyone shed any light on what’s going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I was using a version of Zookeeper (3.3.6) that is incompatible with the current version of Solr (6.1.0).

Solr was trying to use functionality that that version of Zookeeper doesn't have, so it was failing.

Upgrading to Zookeeper 3.4.8 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upload solr config files to zookeeper and try 
[check here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+ZooKeeper+to+Manage+Configuration+Files)

```
$  sh zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -zkhost  <host:port> -confname <name for configset> -solrhome <solrhome> -confdir <path to directory with configset>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The docs suggest that the command `bin/solr create -c mycollection -d data_driven_schema_configs` should upload the config files to Zookeeper as part of the collection creation process. Is this not correct? The command you give appears to run (at least no errors appear in Zookeeper), but there is no folder created called /configs/mycollection as a result...